# Can't create new subdomain on ubuntu 16.04 with ssh

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, subdomain

I am trying to create a subdomain in a `vps` that runs `ubuntu 16.04` so far i have failed, i have read many blogs teaching how, and many of them have the same reponse like [this one](https://daanlenaerts.com/blog/2015/07/05/create-subdomain-with-apache2-on-ubuntu-server/)

i did every step, i did not get errors on the console but the browser just show

```
This site can’t be reached
sypoll.ciea.org.ve’s server IP address could not be found.
```

do i have to do something else? i do not have any panel so i have to do it using ssh.

Comment: The link you shared was about configuring a webserver for a subdomain, but the error that you show indicates that the address doesn't exist in DNS. You need to fix the DNS problem first so that the name resolves to an IP address. I don't think this problem has anything to do with ubuntu or ssh, so you might want to modify the subject of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this has nothing to do with Apache's configuration but is a problem related to DNS. The error message `sypoll.ciea.org.ve’s server IP address could not be found.` indicates that the hostname doesn't yet have an `A` record at all, but currently it has an IP address from a totally different network block than its parent:

```
sypoll.ciea.org.ve.   IN    A     200.74.209.2

inetnum:     200.74.192/19
owner:       Dayco Telecom, C.A.

ciea.org.ve.          IN    A     104.24.103.244
ciea.org.ve.          IN    A     104.24.102.244

CIDR:        104.16.0.0/12
OrgName:     Cloudflare, Inc.
```

If you are trying to add a new Cloudflare VPS, this should probably have an IP from their range. However, the `200.74.209.2` seems to be at least related to you, as it redirects to your main site:

```
$ curl http://200.74.209.2 -vvv
* Connected to 200.74.209.2 (200.74.209.2) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 200.74.209.2
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Date: Thu, 13 Sep 2018 07:43:00 GMT
< Server: Apache
< Location: https://ciea.org.ve/
< Content-Length: 0
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

On the other hand, with hostname `sypoll.ciea.org.ve` we get an *internal server error*:

```
$ curl http://sypoll.ciea.org.ve -vvv
* Connected to sypoll.ciea.org.ve (200.74.209.2) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: sypoll.ciea.org.ve
>
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error
< Date: Thu, 13 Sep 2018 07:43:07 GMT
< Server: Apache
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: close
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

The possible solution is therefore either of these:

- Point `sypoll.ciea.org.ve IN A` to the correct IP address of your VPS.
- Fix `VirtualHost` configuration for `sypoll.ciea.org.ve` on Apache server at `200.74.209.2`.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you have an A record that points to the public IP address of your VPS server.

Also try creating a CNAME record with the sub-domain name that points to your main domain and test again.

This seems like a DNS problem.

Comment: The question clearly shows that this is a DNS problem, not the apache configuration.